# Is it possible to show request body objects in the parameters section of Swagger UI?

Tags: c#, .net, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I am using Swashbuckle with my .Net Core Web API project. I have some GET and POST requests, as usual.

Here's an example:

```
/// <summary>
/// Test request
/// </summary>
[HttpPost("Test")]
[Consumes("application/json")]
[Produces("application/json")]
[SwaggerResponse(200, "Request Executed", typeof(ResponseObject))]
public IActionResult Test([FromBody] TestObject t)
{
    var response = new ResponseObject
    {
        Id = t.Id,
        Name = t.Name,
    };

    return Content(response.JsonSerialize());
}
```

Used objects:

```
/// <summary>
/// An example object
/// </summary>
public class TestObject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Object ID
    /// </summary>
    public string Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Object name
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// An example object
/// </summary>
public class ResponseObject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Object ID
    /// </summary>
    public string Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Object name
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And here's the result:
[image: Text]

What am I expecting to see is a deserialized object in "Parameters" section, as I saw in some other Swagger/Swashbuckle samples (Petstore, for example). Or, at least, something like in OpenAPI v2 specification with `c.SerializeAsV2 = true;`:

[image: Text]

So, the question is, **is it possible to display a deserialized object in "Parameters" section?**

Comment: Can I display the object splitted in parameters, like if I am passing two different query strings? Something like this: https://i.imgur.com/HiKzIvu.png

Comment: No as that’s a query string parameter & you’re using the body - what’s wrong w the current UI? Click try/test & it’ll let you fill it out

Comment: No, nothing wrong, everything works perfectly, just wanted to display everything "better" maybe...

Comment: Ah you can customise the template but that’s another question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you’re using an object & not query string parameters, `TestObject`’s properties won’t be displayed separately as an object is encapsulating.

Having separate fields are for query string parameters.

You can create [custom Swagger layouts](https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/customization/custom-layout/) to display data however you’d like but I’d recommend to keep it as it is, to fall in line with common expectations of the Swagger UI.

Also feel free to have a combination of both; that would also work.